# I want a div to refresh automaticallywithout refreshing whole page

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I have developed a comment system with ajax and its working fine. I want to add a ajax/js code to refresh my time ago div after every 5 seconds so that the time changes while one is on same post.

Please note:

Sir, i just want code to request server to refresh div after a specific time period. I do not want to load page or div but i want contents within that div should be refreshed after a specific period of time.

I'm new in js/ajax and Ii tried this but not working yet

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#showtimeago!").load();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Result I want is:

```
<div class="p_timeAgo" id="showtimeago"> <?php time_stamp($timePost);?></div>
```

Can anyone help me to solve that issue?

Comment: i just want to refresh that div after 5 seconds in which i have to display time ago function

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what UI you are using, here is for the php(since Jquery is same) you can tune this up for your requirement.

```
function loadlink(){
$('#showtimeago').load('test.php',function () {
     $(this).unwrap();
});
}

 loadlink(); // This will run on page load
 setInterval(function(){
  loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
  }, 5000);
```

Try this:

```
<div id="showtimeago"></div>

setInterval(function(){
  $('#showtimeago').load('test.php');
 },5000);
```

test.php is the page the refresher stand.

Comment: sir, i have no external file. i have to just refresh div in which i'm displaying time ago function by using this simple code (<div id="showtimeago"><?php time_stamp($timePost);?></div>

Comment: sorry sir but i'm unable to understand. Is there any way to refresh div's contents after 5 seconds or like. As i have no external file and i have contents in my div and i want that div to refresh its contents agter 5 seconds. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sir, i just want code to request server to refresh div after a specific time period. I do not want to load page or div but i want contents within that div should be refreshed after a specific period of time.